# db4o :how to query objects by store time desc

Tags: java, db4o

```
ObjectContainer oc;
oc.store(new Info(1));
oc.store(new Info(2));
oc.store(new Info(3));

List<Info> list=oc.query(Info.class);
```

The list is:

- Info(1)
- Info(2)
- Info(3)

How to get the list like:

- Info(3)
- Info(2)
- Info(1)

Is there any native method in `db4o`?

`Collections.reverse(list)` throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by [Building SODA Queries](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.13-flare/java/Content/object_lifecycle/querying/soda_query/building_soda_queries.htm).

Build your query like

```
ObjectContainer oc = Db4o.openFile("mydb.yap");
Query query = oc.query();
query.constrain(Info.class);
query.descend("id").orderDescending();
ObjectSet<Info> resultSet = query.execute(); 
// ResultSet would be order desending by id
while(resultSet.hasNext()){
    Info info  = resultSet.next();
    info.getId() ;
}
```